# Как получить список файлов в директории по ftp

Tags: ftp, файлы, php

Если подключится к `ftp`, то `ftp_nlist` показывает все что есть там. А если предварительно поменять через `ftp_chdir`, то пусто. Мне всего то нужно вывести список файлов из директории.

Comment: Какую директорию указываете в ftp_chdir?

Comment: ftp_chdir($conn_id, "www/qqq") и ftp_pwd($conn_id) это подтверждает